# Getting unknown property: craft\feedme\events\FieldEvent::fieldValue

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-feedme

Getting a strange error when trying to check if a field is null when importing via FeedMe

> Getting unknown property: craft\feedme\events\FieldEvent::fieldValue

```
use yii\base\Event;
use craft\feedme\events\FieldEvent;
use craft\feedme\events\ElementEvent;
use craft\helpers\ElementHelper;
use craft\elements\Entry;

Event::on(Fields::class, Fields::EVENT_AFTER_PARSE_FIELD, function(FieldEvent $event) {
    switch($event->feed['name']){
    case 'offers':
    if ($event->fieldHandle === 'merchants' && $event->fieldValue == null) {
    $event->isValid=false;
    }
    break;
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `$event->parsedValue` - see here - https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/blob/develop/src/services/Fields.php#L225

Comment: Don't suppose you could help me with this error I'm now getting `Setting unknown property: craft\feedme\events\FieldEvent::isValid - BaseObject.php: 163`?

Comment: Is this in relation to your bountied post? If I understood correctly, I don’t think it’s doable with Feed Me as it is.

Comment: And in relation to this question, isValid is not available on this event.